# wpa_supplicant throws reason=0 locally_generated=1

Tags: raspberry-pi3, wpa-supplicant

I am running wpa_supplicant on my pi3 board. If I provide credentials using wpa_cli, it tries to connect to the AP but throws out an error as below

```
pi@adityapi:~/Desktop/WifiConnectApp/Rust/latest $ sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -Dnl80211,wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant

wlan0: Trying to associate with 58:6d:8f:3d:27:f4 (SSID='STAP-0' freq=2437 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with 58:6d:8f:3d:27:f4

wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 58:6d:8f:3d:27:f4  [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 58:6d:8f:3d:27:f4 completed [id=0 id_str=]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=58:6d:8f:3d:27:f4 reason=0 locally_generated=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=IN

wlan0: Trying to associate with 58:6d:8f:3d:27:f4 (SSID='STAP-0' freq=2437 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with 58:6d:8f:3d:27:f4

wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=58:6d:8f:3d:27:f4 reason=0 locally_generated=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=IN

wlan0: Trying to associate with 58:6d:8f:3d:27:f4 (SSID='STAP-0' freq=2437 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with 58:6d:8f:3d:27:f4

wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=58:6d:8f:3d:27:f4 reason=0 locally_generated=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=IN

wlan0: Trying to associate with 58:6d:8f:3d:27:f4 (SSID='STAP-0' freq=2437 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with 58:6d:8f:3d:27:f4

wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=58:6d:8f:3d:27:f4 reason=0 locally_generated=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="STAP-0" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=IN
```

How to solve this issue, I referred other places for disabling the 
a) network manager: As I did that, it did not solve this

Answer (score -1):

I read this [post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=146418) and found that pi3 antenna is bit weak, I later tried to run the same command. It works like a charm, I am not too sure what exactly is the problem yet.